# Обработка события listViewSelectedIndexChange

Tags: c#

Всем привет скажите пожалуйста я никак не могу понять как работает это события, у похожего элемента(listBox'a) всё работает нормально, а у listView не работает, вот как какой используется в этом собитие:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection cnt = new MySqlConnection(sql.strProvider))
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM t_link WHERE id = '" + listView1.SelectedItems + "'", cnt);
                try
                {
                    cnt.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Text = reader["question"].ToString();
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (MySqlException ee)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

А вот как выглядит сам элемент:

[image]

Comment: Какого еще друга?

Comment: Это я образно, похожий элемент listBox.

Answer (score 1):

`listView1.SelectedItems` возвращает коллекцию `ListViewItem`'ов. Ваша конструкция

```
"... id = '" + listView1.SelectedItems + "'"
```

вернёт что-то типа `"id='System.ListViewItemCollection'"`.

Надо разобрать коллекцию `ListViewItem`'ов в нужном Вам ключе.

Answer (score 0):

Так пробуйте

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM t_link WHERE id = '" + listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text + "'", cnt);
```